# Neo4j docker-compose to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, neo4j, kompose

I want to go from docker-compose to kubernetes.
I already have a docker-compose, and docker images that work perfectly fine.
Now I have difficulty deploying it to kubernetes, specifically with neo4j...

This is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
    neo4j:
        image: neo4j
        ports:
            - '7474:7474'
            - '7687:7687'
        environment:
            - NEO4J_AUTH=${NEO4J_USERNAME}/${NEO4J_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - neo4j_data:/data

    overseen:
        image: cryxnet/crawnet-overseen
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        environment:
            - NEO4J_USERNAME=${NEO4J_USERNAME}
            - NEO4J_PASSWORD=${NEO4J_PASSWORD}
            - NEO4J_CONNECTION_URI=${NEO4J_CONNECTION_URI}
            - FLASK_APP=${FLASK_APP}
            - FLASK_DEBUG=${FLASK_DEBUG}
        depends_on:
            - neo4j

    dashboard:
        image: cryxnet/crawnet-dashboard
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        environment:
            - FLASK_APP_URL=${FLASK_APP_URL}
        depends_on:
            - overseen

volumes:
    neo4j_data:
```

I converted the above compose with [kompose](https://kompose.io/).

The api and the dashboard work perfectly fine but neo4j always fails.

I did `kubectl logs neo4j` and this was what i got:

```
Failed to read config: Unrecognized setting. No declared setting with name: PORT.7687.TCP.PORT. Cleanup the config or disable 'server.config.strict_validation.enabled' to continue.
Run with '--verbose' for a more detailed error message.
```

Comment: What Kubernetes Deployment does Kompose create?  In my (limited) experience you usually need to clean up the files Kompose generates in some way.  That error suggests to me that the container is starting up (the Kubernetes YAML "makes sense") but there's an application-level settings problem.

Comment: I suggest you use existing Neo4j Helm Chart. Remove from your compose file and only convert your own app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes stores in each container various information about the services in its namespace in the form of environment variables. This info includes, among other, service ports, for which the env-vars take the shape `<svc-name>_PORT_<d+>_TCP_PORT`.

Since your service is named `neo4j`, an env-var `NEO4J_PORT_7687_TCP_PORT` is created, but Neo4J interprets all env-vars starting with `NEO4J_` as configuration parameters. Therefore it complains that no such setting exists.

The solution is to either:

- pass the env-var `NEO4J_server_config_strict__validation_enabled=false` to stop these strict checks (as mentioned in the error message)
- rename your service from `neo4j` to anything else, which will avoid triggering this check

Answer (score 0):

The error states that there is an unrecognized setting in your `neo4j.conf` file.

Check your `neo4j.conf` and remove or comment-out the spurious `PORT.7687.TCP.PORT` setting.